# Error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando enviar dos parámetros a mi webservice mediante POST y se me presenta el error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, cuando intenta ejecutar la linea de codigo 
    `String respuesta = mRequest.execute(nameValuePairs);`

El codigo de mi clase es el siguiente.

```
public class ConexionWS implements MInterfarceTask {

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
RequestQueue request;
Context getApplicationContext;
String codigo, passw;
private  String url;

@Override
public void onPreExecute() {


}

@Override
public void doInBackground() {

    url = "http://10.20.91.61/carnet/webServiceCarnet.php";

    try {
        MRequest mRequest = new MRequest(new URL(url));
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> nameValuePairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        nameValuePairs.put("documento", codigo);
        nameValuePairs.put("pass", passw);

        String respuesta = mRequest.execute(nameValuePairs);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(respuesta);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Por favor me colaboren como solucionar este error.
o si hay otro metodo para enviar datos mediante POST  mas efectivo me lo hagan saber. GRACIAS

Comment: Para hacer una llamada asíncrona (que es lo que te pasa) tienes que heredar de Asynktask. Aquí tienes algo de documentación: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Hola John,. ¿MInterfarceTask no extiende de AsyncTask?

Comment: Jorgesys♦ no... no extiende de nada.

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar 2 lineas en tu clase Main Activity

```js
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Estas de abaj
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```